R in-memory database consumes ZERO memory. Is it really on disk?
I have been experimenting with creating an in-memory SQLite database in R. I have written a program that suggests that generating an in-memory database, and populating it with a table containing a million real numbers, has ZERO effect on the amount of memory consumed by R. In turn, this leads me to suspect that the so-called "in-memory" database is bogus and is really stored on disk. I attach the program that leads me to this conclusion.
On my machine, after I've created the in-memory database and populated it with a large table, and after I've deleted the matrix (mat) used to build the table, the amount of memory consumed is identical to the memory consumed at the beginning of the program, i.e., the in-memory database is consuming ZERO memory.
Am I right, or am I missing something?
Operating system: Windows 11
R version 4.3.1 Patched (2023-10-10 r85312 ucrt) -- "Beagle Scouts"
Here is the complete program:
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

sqlite_in_memory0 = function() {
    #This function measures memory usage via gc.
    mem_report = function() {
        mem_used = gc()
        sum(mem_used[, "(Mb)"])
    }
    message('Memory: Before creating dfr: ', mem_report())

    #Generate a data frame.
    mat = matrix(rnorm(1e8), ncol=10)
    dfr = as.data.frame(mat)
    rm(mat)
    gc()
    colnames(dfr) = letters[1:10]
    #Check size of dfr.
    print(pst('Size of dfr: ', format(object.size(dfr), units='Gb')))
    message('Memory: After creating dfr: ', mem_report())

    #Connect to an in-memory database.
    conx <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
    #Disconnect in-memory database on exit.
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conx))

    #Insert data.
    dbWriteTable(conx, 'dfr', dfr)
    message('\nMemory: After creating in-memory table: ', mem_report())

    #Drop dfr. What is the effect on memory?
    rm(dfr)
    message('Memory: After rm(dfr): ', mem_report())

    #Retrieve data from in-memory database.
    result <- dbReadTable(conx, 'dfr')
    message('dim(result):')
    print(dim(result))
    message('Memory: After dbReadTable: ', mem_report())
}

sqlite_in_memory0()


I guess that it's two different processes. Check your system monitor and you should see an R process and a SQLite process, each with their memory consumption.

gc will report memory used by objects created and managed by R. SQLite is handling it's own memory. You can get more memory info on current R process using ps::ps_memory_info(). I'm not sure it will give what you expect as memory released by gc() is not directly given back to OS.

@nicola When I check Task Manager I see R consumes 119.4 Mb, SQLite consumes 0.4 Mb. So I still think the "in-memory" database is really on disk.

from sqlite documentation "When this is done, no disk file is opened. Instead, a new database is created purely in memory. The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed." and you are calling dbDisconnect(conx) :-) So data is wiped out when you are looking using Task Manager. Try without the dbDisconnect

@Billy34  I did what you suggested. Before calling dbDisconnect(conx) I get the same results: R reports the same memory as at the start of the program, and Task Manager reports SQLite only consuming 0.4 Mb of memory. When I then run dbDisconnect and consult the Windows Memory graph it's like nothing happened, suggesting no memory was released. I appreciate your quoting the documentation but maybe the programmers neglected to read it! ;-)
